# «Дорого́й» или «дороги́м» в данном предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные, выбор-варианта

*Хочу, чтобы подарок не был слишком дорогой*. Или *дорогим*?
Подскажите, как правильно.

Comment: Первоначальное заглавие: *Спряжение "дорогой" или "дорогим" в данном предложении*. Татьяна, просто для сведения: *дорогой* — это прилагательное, оно не спрягается, а склоняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Розенталь, "Справочник по правописанию и стилистике":

> Именная часть составного сказуемого может быть выражена формой
> именительного и формой творительного падежа; ср. конструкции с одним и
> тем же лексическим составом сказуемого: *И в семье его Савельич был
> свой человек* (Мельников-Печерский). – У *Ивашиных он был своим
> человеком* (Чехов). Обычно в этих случаях **именительный падеж
> указывает на устойчивый признак предмета, на постоянно присущую ему
> качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж указывает на
> временный признак** (выделение моё - N). Ср. у Пушкина: Г*ерманн был
> сын обрусевшего немца. – Бопре в отечестве своём был парикмахером,
> потом в Пруссии солдатом*.

Поскольку в вашем случае речь о цене подарка, что является временной характеристикой, то верно будет использовать творительный падеж: **Хочу, чтобы подарок не был слишком дорогим.**

Впрочем, Розенталь ниже замечает:

> Однако это разграничение не проводится последовательно, например: *А
> Давид… был сначала пастух* (В. Панова) (употреблена форма именительного
> падежа, хотя указывается временный признак); *Дом, мимо которого бежала
> Аночка, был городской школой* (Федин) (употреблена форма творительного
> падежа, хотя имеется в виду постоянный признак).

Так что строгого правила нет, есть лишь тенденция.

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от падежа:

(Каким?)-дорогим, это в творительном падеже.

А (какой?)-дорогой, это в именительном.

Тут основа 'подарок был'.
Значит подарок в именительном падеже. Тогда и зависимое прилагательное тоже.

Comment: Это не зависит от падежа подлежащего. См. мой ответ и указанный там справочник.

Comment: Ваш ответ такой, как если бы вас спросили, какой падеж выбрать, а вы бы ответили: это зависит от падежа.